# How to make array calculations more efficient in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I recently learned to use arrays as part of my VBA macros. I understand they are an integral part of using VBA effectively, so I'd like to learn more about how to process through arrays efficiently. I've searched around a bit and found a few articles, but if there's something major I'm missing please let me know.

Here is an example code, a subroutine that finds the N'th prime number. It does this by using trial division on an array of primes, dynamically adding new primes to the array.

```
Sub FindNthPrime()
    StartTime = Timer
    Dim Counter, n, i As Single
    Dim Primes() As Double  'An array of primes so far
    Dim TestVal As Double
    Dim PrimeTest As Boolean
    
    n = 100000  'Find the n'th prime number
    
    ReDim Primes(0)
    Primes(0) = 2  'Start the array at 2
    Counter = 1    'Start the Counter at 1
    TestVal = 3    'Start testing with 3
    
    Do Until Counter = n
        PrimeTest = True
        For i = 0 To UBound(Primes)
            If Primes(i) > (TestVal ^ 0.5) Then Exit For
            If TestVal Mod Primes(i) = 0 Then
                PrimeTest = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        
        If PrimeTest = True Then
            ReDim Preserve Primes(UBound(Primes) + 1)
            Primes(UBound(Primes)) = TestVal
            Counter = UBound(Primes) + 1
        End If
        
        TestVal = TestVal + 2
    Loop
    
    Debug.Print Primes(UBound(Primes))
    Debug.Print Timer - StartTime
End Sub
```

On a basic benchmark test, this code does outperform a brute-force trial division algorithm without using arrays (testing all odd numbers up to the square-root of our test number), but not by much. As primes get large, in this case the 100,000's prime, we're seeing calculation times surpassing 5 seconds on my machine.

TL;DR: Any tips on making the above code more efficient?

Comment: This might be better posted on [codereview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dim Counter, n, i As Single`
The default type is `variant` so counter and `n` are `variants`
`Redim Preserve` is an expensive option so start with a large array size and increment in `Redim Preserve` with a large number.
Use `Long` wherever possible rather than `single` or `double`
But most of the time will probably be taken by `Mod` and `^`